# RtlSetProcessIsCritical vs NtSetInformationProcess

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ntdll

I want to set my process as critical. I understand all the risks, just want to know **what to call**.

I tried the RtlSetProcessIsCritical method and it worked as it should. Though i tested it on Windows XP virtual machine, one website claimed that RtlSetProcessIsCritical was first presented on Windows 8, and that I need to call NtSetInformationProcess instead. So what do I call? Is there really any difference between those two functions?

Comment: Please tell us the name of your program so we can avoid it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one website claimed that RtlSetProcessIsCritical was first presented on Windows 8

That is incorrect.  It is available in Windows XP and 7, as well.

However, even to this day, `RtlSetProcessIsCritical()` is still *undocumented* by Microsoft.  Which means, you really should not be using it at all.  But, you have already decided to use it, so...

> Is there really any difference between those two functions?

`RtlSetProcessIsCritical` simply calls `NtSetInformationProcess()` internally.  `RtlSetProcessIsCritical()` is in `NTDLL.DLL`, whereas `NtSetInformationProcess()` is in `NTOSKRNL` (the Windows Kernel), so the former will just call the latter.